# No such file or directory after deleting file , ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote an code to assign documents to patients:

```
file = Dir.entries('C:\Sites\what2\uploadnew').reject {|entry| entry == "." || entry == ".."}

file.each do |f|
  a = File.read('C:\Sites\what2\uploadnew' + '/' + f) + f

  @patients.each do |patient|
    if [patient.nachnahme, patient.vorname, patient.geburtsdatum].all? {|i| a.include? i }
      first = Patient.find_by_id(patient.id)
      second = first.images.create(:url => 'C:\Sites\what2\uploadsave' + '/' + f[0..-5] + '.tif')
      File.delete 'C:/Sites/what2/uploadnew/' + f
    end
  end  
end
```

Like you can see at the end of the code I delete the file:

```
File.delete 'C:/Sites/what2/uploadnew/' + f
```

But somehow this causes problems. I get the error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in DocumentsController#index

No such file or directory - C:/Sites/what2/uploadnew/filename.txt
```

The strange thing is that the command works and ruby really deletes the file. Means that the  file cannot exist! SO why asks ruby for this file?

Comment: If `@patients.each` runs more than once for each file name, there's the possibility that you're going to attempt to delete that same file name more than once. It will succeed the first time, then fail the subsequent times since it's already deleted. So during a given loop of `@patients.each` your `if` must be succeeding more than once, which would lead to the error.

Comment: Ok i will try it with exists? (filename) Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure overall what your logic means semantically, but the simple solution would be to check for the existence of the file before you delete it. `file_name = 'C:/Sites/what2/uploadnew/' + f ` then `File.delete file_name if File.file? file_name`. `file?` is like `exists?` but succeeds only if it is a regular file (as opposed to a directory).

Comment: @mbratch please post it as answer, so that i can mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure overall what your logic means semantically, so there may be reasons why the file delete shouldn't be repeated, but the simple solution would be to check for the existence of the file before you delete it.

```
file_name = 'C:/Sites/what2/uploadnew/' + f
File.delete file_name if File.file? file_name
```

Since it's a normal file, I'm suggesting to use `.file?` as opposed to `exists?`.